# Xcode 10.1: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" for all code in linked project

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, xcode10

This project has compiled a thousand times before and I didn't change anything in my code. However, I am sure that I've updated Xcode since the last time I opened this workspace/project and tried to compile. I've got a workspace that contains some other projects that I use for code I share across various apps.

When I build, I get a LONG list of linker errors wherein it complains that it can't find the symbols for any of the classes in my linked projects (`InADay_ApplicationCore` and `InADay_Financial`).

Here is just one of the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InADayApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
```

This app's `AppDelegate` extends my `InADayApplicationDelegate` from my shared project `InADay_ApplicationCore.xcodeproj`. This has always worked, I'm not sure what is going wrong now.

```
#import "InADayApplicationDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate : InADayApplicationDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

And my `InADayApplicationDelegate` is declared like this:

```
@interface InADayApplicationDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

I've got these other projects included in my workspace:

[image]

And I've set them up as Target Dependencies as well as set to be linked:

[image]

If I close this and then separately open the linked projects, I'm able to build those projects without a problem.

I even located the `libInADay_ApplicationCore.a` file, and listed the symbols in it and found it:

```
$ nm /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InADay_ApplicationCore-fzyevmbuqkgqgebkhqhuegaphzdb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libInADay_ApplicationCore.a | fgrep InADayApplicationDelegate
...
0000000000002dd8 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_InADayApplicationDelegate
...
$
```

What has gotten messed up? Why can't I build?

Here is the full command from Xcode's build log:

> Ld
>   /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/10biiFinancialCalculator
>   normal armv7 (in target: 10biiFinancialCalculator)
>       cd /Users/kenny/inaday2/svn-10bii-ios/trunk/apps/ios/10biiFinancialCalculator
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CorePlot
>   -filelist /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/10biiFinancialCalculator.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/10biiFinancialCalculator_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework CorePlot -ObjC -framework MobileCoreServices -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -lz.1.2.5 -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework UIKit -framework
>   Foundation -framework Pods_10biiFinancialCalculator -Xlinker
>   -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/10biiFinancialCalculator_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/10biiFinancialCalculator-ewamouydosmazceglfabvcraukxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/10biiFinancialCalculator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/10biiFinancialCalculator